# Drag behaviour wrong after UIView transformation

Tags: ios, swift, transform, draggable

I have a custom `DraggableView` that subclasses `UIImageView`. I take a photo with the camera, add the resulting `UIImage` to a `DraggableView` and then I can happily drag it around the screen, as intended.

Now, if the original photo was taken in landscape, I rotate it using:

```
if (image?.size.width > image?.size.height)
{
   self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2))
}
```

When I apply this transformation, the drag behaviour still works, but the directions are all wrong - if I drag left, the image moves up, not left. If I drag up, the image moves right, not up.

How do I fix this? I guess it is something to do with the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` being bound to the non-transformed view?

**Edit:** Current `UIPanGestureRecognizer` handler:

```
func onPhotoDrag(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer?)
{
    let translation = recognizer!.translationInView(recognizer?.view)
    recognizer!.view!.center = CGPointMake(recognizer!.view!.center.x 
            + translation.x, recognizer!.view!.center.y + translation.y);
    recognizer?.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: recognizer?.view)

    if (recognizer!.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended)
    {
        let velocity = recognizer!.velocityInView(recognizer?.view)
        let magnitude = sqrt((velocity.x * velocity.x) 
                + (velocity.y * velocity.y))
        let slideMult = magnitude / 300;
        let slideFactor = 0.1 * slideMult;
        let finalPoint = CGPointMake(recognizer!.view!.center.x 
                + (velocity.x * slideFactor), 
                recognizer!.view!.center.y + (velocity.y * slideFactor));

        // Animate the drag, and allow the drag delegate to do its work
        DraggableView.animateWithDuration(Double(slideFactor), 
                delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut,
                animations: { recognizer?.view?.center = finalPoint },
                completion: {(_) -> Void in self.dragDelegate?.onDragEnd(self)})
    } // if: gesture ended
}
```

Comment: Could you post the panGestureHandler code of your draggable view?

Comment: Instead of DraggableView subclassing UIImageView, make it a subclass of UIView, then add the rotated UIImageView as a child.

Comment: Edited to add the handler. I do the rotate in the `init` of the `DraggableView`,  but trying the method in the answer made no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update:

Thanks for posting your code.  I pasted your code into my `DraggableImageView` and reproduced your problem.  Although my version was handling the rotated view (without the animation), yours was going sideways.

The difference is that my code asks for the `translationInView` in the `superview` of the draggable view.  You need to ask for the `translationInView` and `velocityInView` in the `superview` of your draggable view.

Change this line:

```
let translation = recognizer!.translationInView(recognizer?.view)
```

to:

```
let translation = recognizer!.translationInView(recognizer?.view?.superview)
```

and change this:

```
let velocity = recognizer!.velocityInView(recognizer?.view)
```

to:

```
let velocity = recognizer!.velocityInView(recognizer?.view?.superview)
```

and all will be happy.

---

#### Previous Answer:

Try this version:

```
class DraggableImageView: UIImageView {
    
    override var image: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            if (image?.size.width > image?.size.height)
            {
                self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2))
            }
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        self.setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        
        self.setup()
    }
    
    func setup() {
        self.userInteractionEnabled = true
        
        let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
        panGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(draggedView(_:)))
        self.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
    }
    
    func moveByDeltaX(deltaX: CGFloat, deltaY: CGFloat) {
        self.center.x += deltaX
        self.center.y += deltaY
    }
    
    func draggedView(sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        if let dragView = sender.view as? DraggableImageView, superview = dragView.superview {
            superview.bringSubviewToFront(dragView)
            let translation = sender.translationInView(superview)
            sender.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: superview)
            dragView.moveByDeltaX(translation.x, deltaY: translation.y)
        }
    }
}
```

Use example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let dragView = DraggableImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 96, height: 128))
    
    dragView.image = UIImage(named: "landscapeImage.png")
    
    self.view.addSubview(dragView)
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and I see what this is trying to do, but it didn't work. As requested by @vacawama, I've added the current pan handler.

Comment: This works as described, and I understand why. Thanks!

Comment: I should also say that this stops me from dragging from behind the photo on top (as I could do previously) as the frame being used for the drag is now much bigger, but I can sort that out later.

Comment: Hmmm.  I don't understand your latest comment.  This change is merely a mathematical transformation of the coordinates into the correct view coordinates.  How is that changing what you can select?

Comment: The `DraggableView` frame is just shy of the bounds of the display, and then I aspect fit the image, which previously was bound to the drag behaviour. I think I need to be smarter with sizing that frame.